# Data integrity between scenarios in Specflow using Testcontainers (.net core)

Tags: c#, .net, specflow, testcontainers

I tried to use Testcontainers in my c# specflow. But it seems Scpeflow didn't wait for the container to start when i initiated my container in my custome WebapplicationFacotry class.
At last I created a new container in my BeforFeature hook and passed it to my WebapplicationFactory class.

```
[BeforeFeature]
        public static async Task BuildAndStartContainerAsync(IObjectContainer objectContainer,
            FeatureContext featureContext)
        {
 var container = new PostgreSqlBuilder()
                .WithImage("postgres:15")
                .WithDatabase("customers")
                .WithUsername("customeruser")
                .WithPortBinding(5432, 5432)
                .WithPassword("AdminP003545")
                .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilPortIsAvailable(5432))
                .Build();
            try
            {
                await container.StartAsync();
                
            }
            finally
            {
                var (stdout, stderr) = await container.GetLogsAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(stdout);
            }

            var factory = new IntegrationTestFactory<Program, CustomerDBContext>(container);

            objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs(factory, "factory");
}
```

my WebApplicationFactory

```
[Binding]
public class IntegrationTestFactory<TProgram, TDbContext> : WebApplicationFactory<TProgram>
    where TProgram : class where TDbContext : DbContext
{
    public PostgreSqlContainer _databaseContainer;

    public IntegrationTestFactory(PostgreSqlContainer databaseContainer)
    {
        _databaseContainer = databaseContainer;
    }
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.RemoveDbContext<TDbContext>();
            var conn = _databaseContainer.GetConnectionString();
            services.AddDbContext<TDbContext>(options => { options.UseNpgsql(conn); });
         
        });
    }
}
```

My Step Defintions class:

```
 public CustomerManagerStepsDf(IObjectContainer objectContainer,ScenarioContext scenarioContext )
    {
        _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
        
        _testFactory=objectContainer.Resolve<IntegrationTestFactory<Program,CustomerDBContext>>("factory");
        _client = _testFactory.CreateDefaultClient(new Uri("http://localhost:5160"));
    }
```

Now there are other problems.

First: As scenarios run simultancy my data integrity breaks and some scenario fails.
Second: Should I continue with initiating a container in BeforeScenario to guarantee scenario-specific containers and data isolation?
Third: What strategies or best practices can be employed to ensure data integrity when running scenarios concurrently?

Comment: Overriding the default module configuration is only necessary in very rare cases and is usually not recommended. Your build configuration does not follow the recommended [best practices](https://dotnet.testcontainers.org/api/best_practices/) either. Please try using the default configuration (overriding the database, username, and password is fine though). Your wait strategy indicates readiness too early (the module's wait strategy is more complex), and your static port binding will clash when running tests in parallel against multiple instances.

Comment: Thanks @AndreHofmeister for your tips. I updated my builder with best practices and also put Testcontainers creation in the [BeforScenario] hook.
Parallel test works now correctly but it will create one docker per scenario. As i'm a newbie in Spceflow  Is it the right way? Should we have a lot of containers for a large feature test?

Comment: This really depends on your tests. It is not easy to answer. You need to distinguish between certain tests. Tests usually run in a non-deterministic order. Tests that manipulate data or perform destructive operations usually require new instances, while all other tests can share a single instance to increase test performance and execution time. The underlying test framework has built-in mechanics to share instances among tests. This is not something Testcontainers takes care of, as we do not know the actual test framework being used.

Answer (score 0):

Initiating Container in BeforeScenario

```
[BeforeScenario]
public async Task BeforeScenario(IObjectContainer objectContainer)
{
   var container = container

   objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs(container, "scenarioContainer");
}
```

data integrity problems

use separate databases
database cleanup

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).